# How to read many values separated by newlines

Tags: python, file, parsing

I have a text file that looks like this

```
# a   b   c   d    e    f    g

  1.0 3.0 6.0 4.0  5.0  9.0  4.0
  1.2 7.0 6.0 4.3  5.0  8.0  7.8
  1.7 8.0 6.4 4.1  8.7  9.9  4.7

  1.3 3.0 6.1 4.0  5.0  9.0  4.8
  1.5 3.2 6.3 4.0  5.7  9.0  4.5
  1.7 2.0 8.5 4.0  5.3  9.0  4.3
  1.7 3.2 8.0 4.0  5.1  9.0  4.3

  1.0 3.0 6.0 4.0  4.0  9.0  9.1
  1.3 3.1 6.8 4.0  5.5  9.0  5.0
  1.0 3.5 6.1 4.0  5.7  9.0  4.6
```

pattern (the number of chunks of data, separated by the newline is variable for each file, and the number of lines for each chunk is also variable). What is the cleanest way to read the data in column by column, but to separate each column variable into the different chunks? So far I just read the first two columns like:

```
  A = []
  B = []
  a = []
  b = []

  col_a = 0
  col_b = 1

  with open(fileName, 'r') as fid:
      header = fid.readline()
      next(fid)
      for line in fid:
          d = line.split()
          if not d: # If a newline
              A.append(a)
              B.append(b)
              a = []
              b = []

          if d: # If not a newline
              a.append(d[col_a])
              b.append(d[col_b])
```

Comment: You should use `pandas`: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: @Borja unfortunately I can't get pandas on my system

Comment: @Jack, that's a pity, because pandas would be an ideal solution for you. But you still can use: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @martineau Im using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want the data in each column divided up, but here's one way of doing it. After processing the file `columns` will be a list of lists of tuples, where the data for column 2 will be in `columns[1]` (since Python counts from zero) and the tuple containing the first block of values in that column will be in `columns[1][0]`. In the sample data file these are `'3.0'`, `'7.0'`, and `'8.0'`.

The code's been written to work in Python 2.6+ as well as Python 3.x.

```
import csv
import io  # requires Python 2.6+

filename = 'many_values_per_line.txt'

with io.open(filename, 'r', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(csv_input)
    blocks = []
    block = []
    for row in csv_input:
        if row:
            block.append(row)
        elif block:
            blocks.append(zip(*block))
            block = []
    if block:  # final block
        blocks.append(zip(*block))
    columns = [list(i) for i in zip(*blocks)]

for i, column in enumerate(columns):
    print('column {}: {}'.format(i, column))
print('')
print('columns[1][0]: {}'.format(columns[1][0]))
```

Output:

```
column 0: [('1.0', '1.2', '1.7'), ('1.3', '1.5', '1.7', '1.7'), ('1.0', '1.3', '1.0')]
column 1: [('3.0', '7.0', '8.0'), ('3.0', '3.2', '2.0', '3.2'), ('3.0', '3.1', '3.5')]
column 2: [('6.0', '6.0', '6.4'), ('6.1', '6.3', '8.5', '8.0'), ('6.0', '6.8', '6.1')]
column 3: [('4.0', '4.3', '4.1'), ('4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0'), ('4.0', '4.0', '4.0')]
column 4: [('5.0', '5.0', '8.7'), ('5.0', '5.7', '5.3', '5.1'), ('4.0', '5.5', '5.7')]
column 5: [('9.0', '8.0', '9.9'), ('9.0', '9.0', '9.0', '9.0'), ('9.0', '9.0', '9.0')]
column 6: [('4.0', '7.8', '4.7'), ('4.8', '4.5', '4.3', '4.3'), ('9.1', '5.0', '4.6')]

columns[1][0]: ('3.0', '7.0', '8.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#module-csv) library and the itertools [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.groupby) function. The script creates a list of blocks, with each block holding a list of columns:

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv

blocks = []

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for k, g in groupby(csv_input, lambda x: len(x)):
        if k:
            blocks.append(zip(*g))

for block in blocks:
    print block
```

It prints the following:

```
[('1.0', '1.2', '1.7'), ('3.0', '7.0', '8.0'), ('6.0', '6.0', '6.4'), ('4.0', '4.3', '4.1'), ('5.0', '5.0', '8.7'), ('9.0', '8.0', '9.9'), ('4.0', '7.8', '4.7')]
[('1.3', '1.5', '1.7', '1.7'), ('3.0', '3.2', '2.0', '3.2'), ('6.1', '6.3', '8.5', '8.0'), ('4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0'), ('5.0', '5.7', '5.3', '5.1'), ('9.0', '9.0', '9.0', '9.0'), ('4.8', '4.5', '4.3', '4.3')]
[('1.0', '1.3', '1.0'), ('3.0', '3.1', '3.5'), ('6.0', '6.8', '6.1'), ('4.0', '4.0', '4.0'), ('4.0', '5.5', '5.7'), ('9.0', '9.0', '9.0'), ('9.1', '5.0', '4.6')]
```

The `zip(*....)` line will convert your list of rows into a list of columns.

For example, to display column 2 from block 1, you could do the following:

```
print blocks[0][1]
```

Which displays:

```
('3.0', '7.0', '8.0')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to somehow also divide the data in each column according to which chunk it came from.

Comment: I have updated the script to deal with the blocks independently. Note, Python counts from 0.